# Cannot install Magento Cloud cli on local

Tags: magento2, magento-cloud

I have problem with install the Magento 2 CLI on my local, do you know what can I do next? thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add `sudo` before `php` not before the  `curl`